# DBGp proxy error Handler response error: Error reading command: Don't understand command '[507]'

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

Remote debugging using Xdebug DBGp proxy and PhpStorm:

- Ubuntu 22.10
- PHP 8.1
- Xdebug v3.1.2
- Xdebug DBGp proxy (0.4.2-dev)

```
./dbgpProxy 
Xdebug DBGp proxy (0.4.2-dev)
Copyright 2020 by Derick Rethans
2023-02-13 07:16:48.394 [warn] [SSL] The 'certs/fullchain.pem' file could not be found, not enabling SSL listeners
2023-02-13 07:16:48.394 [info] [dbgpProxy] Proxy started
2023-02-13 07:16:48.395 [info] [server] Started server server on 127.0.0.1:9003
2023-02-13 07:16:48.395 [info] [server] Started client server on 127.0.0.1:9001
```

Xdebug settings:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

SSH settings:

```
RemoteForward 9001 localhost:9001
LocalForward 9001 localhost:9001
```

Tools -> DBGp proxy -> Register IDE

```
2023-02-13 07:17:08.768 [info] [server] Start new client connection from 127.0.0.1:33682
2023-02-13 07:17:08.839 [info] [proxyinit] [POLYANIN] Added connection for IDE Key 'POLYANIN': 127.0.0.1:9001
2023-02-13 07:17:08.840 [info] [server] Closing client connection from 127.0.0.1:33682
```

The error:

```
2023-02-13 07:28:18.141 [info] [proxy-client] [POLYANIN] Found connection for IDE Key 'POLYANIN': 127.0.0.1:9001
2023-02-13 07:28:18.141 [info] [proxy-client] [POLYANIN] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9001
2023-02-13 07:28:18.142 [info] [proxy-client] [POLYANIN] IDE connected
2023-02-13 07:28:18.142 [info] [server] Start new client connection from 127.0.0.1:33694
2023-02-13 07:28:18.142 [info] [proxy-client] [POLYANIN] Init forwarded, start pipe
2023-02-13 07:28:18.142 [warn] [server] Handler response error: Error reading command: Don't understand command '[507]'
2023-02-13 07:28:18.142 [info] [server] Closing client connection from 127.0.0.1:33694
2023-02-13 07:28:18.192 [info] [proxy-client] [POLYANIN] IDE closed connection
```

I put a breakpoint and refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the DBGp proxy this way, as it always sends the debug data to the host where the IDE registration with the key came from.
Since you are using a tunnel, it always comes from `127.0.0.1`; this is why you get `Found connection for IDE Key 'POLYANIN': 127.0.0.1:9001`, and this is why you get the error message - the proxy tries to send the debug data to itself instead of PhpStorm.

There is an extremely ugly workaround - you can modify the proxy code so that it uses the IDE key as a port number to connect to:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010264920-xdebug-multiple-developers-php-storm-dbgpproxy